# Nested loops: representing factors of numbers up to 20 graphically

Tags: python, python-2.7, iteration, nested-loops

I want to write a program in python that represents the factors of numbers graphically. I don't know how to explain exactly what I mean with words, so I will describe the output I am looking for:

```
* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
* * - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
* - * - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
* * - * - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
* - - - * - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
* * * - - * - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
* - - - - - * - - - - - - - - - - - - -
* * - * - - - * - - - - - - - - - - - -
* - * - - - - - * - - - - - - - - - - -
* * - - * - - - - * - - - - - - - - - -
* - - - - - - - - - * - - - - - - - - -
* * * * - * - - - - - * - - - - - - - -
* - - - - - - - - - - - * - - - - - - -
* * - - - - * - - - - - - * - - - - - -
* - * - * - - - - - - - - - * - - - - -
* * - * - - - * - - - - - - - * - - - -
* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - * - - -
* * * - - * - - * - - - - - - - - * - -
* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - * -
* * - * * - - - - * - - - - - - - - - *
```

I wrote this program:

```
for i in range (1,21):
    for j in range (1,21):
        if i%j == 0:
            print '*',
        else:
            print '_',
```

But the output is on a single line and I don't know how to fix that. I played around with the commas but I still don't get what I want.

By the way, almost all of my questions are about problems with formatting the output. How can I improve at doing that? There is no chapter in a book or tutorial dedicated to formatting the output so I don't know how to improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `print` statement in your first `for` loop:

```
for i in range (1,21):
    for j in range (1,21):
        if i%j == 0:
            print '*',
        else:
            print '-',
    print

[OUTPUT]
* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
* * - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
* - * - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
* * - * - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
* - - - * - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
* * * - - * - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
* - - - - - * - - - - - - - - - - - - -
* * - * - - - * - - - - - - - - - - - -
* - * - - - - - * - - - - - - - - - - -
* * - - * - - - - * - - - - - - - - - -
* - - - - - - - - - * - - - - - - - - -
* * * * - * - - - - - * - - - - - - - -
* - - - - - - - - - - - * - - - - - - -
* * - - - - * - - - - - - * - - - - - -
* - * - * - - - - - - - - - * - - - - -
* * - * - - - * - - - - - - - * - - - -
* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - * - - -
* * * - - * - - * - - - - - - - - * - -
* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - * -
* * - * * - - - - * - - - - - - - - - *
```

### ALTERNATIVE

```
b = [' '.join('*' if i==j or i%j==0 else '-' for j in range(1,21)) for i in range(1,21)]

for i in b:
    print i

[SAME OUTPUT]
```

#### Tom Fenech's suggestion

You could do it in one line as:

```
print '\n'.join(' '.join('*' if i % j == 0 else '_' for j in xrange(1,21)) for i in xrange(1,21))
```

Comment: @user2357, No problem. I'll be updating my answer in a few minutes with a more condensed method. If you're interested, stick around. :)

Comment: Definitely interested! Hopefully a one liner :P

Comment: @user2357, Answer updated. The main code is one-line. The printing part doesn't count. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Nice! I need to start using join more, I never use it.

Comment: Your "one line" version could be: `print '\n'.join([' '.join(['*' if i % j == 0 else '_' for j in xrange(1,21)]) for i in xrange(1,21)])`

Comment: @TomFenech, Thank you very much. I have included your suggestion in my answer.

Comment: Note that in the one line version you can drop all the `[]`. It will continue to work and it will avoid wasting memory creating lists that are immediately garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

just include a print  statement after every iteration of your first for loop ... or in other words I mean that you have to print a line break every time , the i is incremented in your case and in python you can print a line break by using following syntax :

```
print
```

or

```
print "\n"
```